# Spark accumulators thread-safety (LongAccumulator seems to be broken)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, concurrency

I'm writing a custom `AccumulatorV2` and want it to be properly synchronized.

I've read a few post about the Spark `AccumulatorV2` concurrency problems and as far as I understand

1) Writes to an accumulator happens before reads and vise versa

2) But writes to an accumulator from different partitions are not synchronized

So accumulator's `add` method must support concurrent access.

Here is the proof:

```
object MyAccumulator {
  val uniqueId: AtomicInteger = new AtomicInteger()
}

//Just a regular int accumulator but with a delay inside Add method
class MyAccumulator(var w: Int = 0) extends AccumulatorV2[Int, Int] {

  //log this id to prove that updates happen on the same object
  val thisAccId = MyAccumulator.uniqueId.incrementAndGet()

  override def isZero: Boolean = w == 0

  override def copy(): AccumulatorV2[Int, Int] = new MyAccumulator(w)

  override def reset(): Unit = w = 0

  override def add(v: Int): Unit = {
    println(s"Start adding $thisAccId " + Thread.currentThread().getId)
    Thread.sleep(500)
    w += v
    println(s"End adding $thisAccId " + Thread.currentThread().getId)
  }

  override def merge(other: AccumulatorV2[Int, Int]): Unit = w += other.value

  override def value: Int = w
}

object Test extends App {
  val conf = new SparkConf()
  conf.setMaster("local[5]")
  conf.setAppName("test")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 50, 10)
  val acc = new MyAccumulator
  sc.register(acc)
  rdd.foreach(x => acc.add(x))
  println(acc.value)

  sc.stop()
}
```

Output example:

```
Start adding 1 73
Start adding 1 77
Start adding 1 76
Start adding 1 74
Start adding 1 75
End adding 1 74
End adding 1 75
Start adding 1 74
End adding 1 76
End adding 1 77
End adding 1 73
Start adding 1 77
Start adding 1 76
....
....
....
1212
```

We can see that there are several threads are inside the `add` method concurrently and the result is wrong (it must be 1275).

Then I looked into the source code of built-in accumulators (e.g. `org.apache.spark.util.LongAccumulator`) and found no trace of synchronization. It uses just mutable `var`s.

How can it work at all?

UPDATE:
LongAccumulator is broken indeed (the following code fails) :

```
object LongAccumulatorIsBroken extends App {
  val conf = new SparkConf()
  conf.setMaster("local[5]")
  conf.setAppName("test")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val rdd = sc.parallelize((1 to 50000).map(x => 1), 1000)
  val acc = new LongAccumulator
  sc.register(acc)
  rdd.foreach(x => acc.add(x))
  val value = acc.value
  println(value)
  sc.stop()
  assert(value == 50000, message = s"$value is not 50000")
}
```

Comment: I am getting the correct result on spark 2.1.1. I have also added `System.identityHashCode(this)` to your printouts to demonstrate, that simultaneous calls to `add` occur on different instances of accumulator.

Comment: In my case `System.identityHashCode(MyAccumulator.this)` is always the same. Also running on 2.1.1 gives the same result.

Comment: Gotta be something wrong with your setup then. Accumulators are not supposed to be thread-safe by design. See here for some details:
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-accumulators.html

Comment: I'm running the example as is (from IntellijIdea). Also I've added the example that breaks the `LongAccumulator` itself

Comment: I guess, intellij is doing something wrong (woudn't be the first time). 
Try running in spark-shell instead.

Comment: I got the same result running it from command line via `java -cp myJar.jar LongAccumulatorIsBroken`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, but all my Spark instances are 2.2.0. Check the Spark GUI (`http://127.0.0.1:4040`) for failed or restarted tasks. The GUI also shows the accumulators in each stage, but only the named ones. Thus, change `sc.register(acc)` to `sc.register(acc, "acc")` first. Insert a delay before `sc.stop()`, otherwise you have to be really quick in opening the GUI page.

Comment: @simpadjo running java from command line isn't the same thing.
You need to use spark-shell or spark-submit

Comment: This issue is not reproduced if I run it in the spark console. Moreover, it is not reproduced if I change `LongAccumulatorIsBroken extends App` to `def main(args: Array[String]): Unit` .
In the second case accumulator instance is created per thread (so no concurrency issues occur) and in the first - only one shared accumulator instance is created. 

Is it a proper behavior?